# How to export models without losing precision?

Tags: export

In Blender a coordinate might be 1.5. When exporting the model to Houdini, that coordinate becomes 1.500001. This is not consistent either, even with seemingly perfectly rounded coordinates using the Python script below in Blender, some coordinates still lose their precision when exported, which is breaking a Boolean operation in Houdini.

This does mostly work, but would not round 1.50001 to 1.5, for example:

```
import bpy

for c, obj in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects):
    for vert in obj.data.vertices:
        vert.co.x = round(vert.co.x, 1)
        vert.co.y = round(vert.co.y, 1)
        vert.co.z = round(vert.co.z, 1)
```

Interestingly, if I go through and manually re-input the coordinate, the precision is no longer lost. Blender is often displaying the coordinate at 1.50000, but internally it is 1.500001.

This is particularly problematic when using an array modifier, because apparently Blender can't keep adding 2 and it just needs to add an extra 0.000001 for no reason.

The boolean operation in Houdini is used to optimise meshes, and this precision error is causing them to be 10-20% larger than they otherwise should be.
I can't do the rounding in Houdini because some of the vertices aren't necessarily snapped to the grid.

**Edit:** Added a partial solution by rounding all vertices to the 5th decimal place in Houdini. This loses some precision, but arguably that is simply a degree of imprecision Blender adds but does not display anyway. Not sure if it will become a problem later. Here is the vex code that was placed in a point wrangle node:

```
@P = rint(@P*100000)/100000;
```